# Move existing file to another branch, put a new version of this file to master

Tags: git

I have a file `Main.java` and two versions of it: one version is located in my local and remote repositories, on branch master. The second version is located in another computer and changes in it have never been tracked.

I need to make the second file the master's version, while moving the first version to a new branch.

I'm not sure how to accomplish it, considering git never knew of the second version  and changes in it never were commited in any form.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Step 1: Create a new branch (but stay on `master`). Step 2: Copy the other file into your repository and commit it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

*All* commits in any Git repository hold snapshots of files.  *Each* commit holds a complete snapshot of *all* of the files that it holds.

That is, think of your Git repository as a collection of commits (because it is), with each commit strung together in a sort of backwards fashion.  Let's draw a really simple repository with just three commits, and call those commits `A`, `B`, and `C` to make it easy to talk about them:

```
A <-B <-C
```

The *last* commit `C`, which is really identified by some big ugly hash ID—every commit has some big ugly hash ID, unique to that particular commit—remembers the hash ID of the *second* commit `B`.  We say that `C` *points to* `B`, or that `B` is `C`'s *parent*.  The second commit `B` remembers the hash ID of commit `A`, so that `B` points to `A`.

Commit `A` is the very first commit we ever made.  The repository was totally empty when we made it, so it doesn't point back anywhere else: it has *no* parent.  There's always one commit like this in any non-empty repository.

Let's say we had files `README.md` and `Main.java` when we made commit `A`:

```
git init
git add README.md Main.java
git commit
```

That means commit `A` contains *some version of* `README.md` and `Main.java`.  These snapshots, saved in commit `A`, are read-only (and compressed and Git-ified to save space and be read-only).  Nothing can or will ever change anything at all about commit `A`: all parts of any commit are frozen for all time.

That's why `B` points to `A`, but `A` doesn't point to `B`, too: `A` is frozen now.  We don't actually *have* `B` yet.  Now we change `Main.java` or `README.md`, or make a whole new file.  All of these changes don't happen in the commit at all: they happen in our *work-tree*, which Git gives to us to let us do our work.  Let's say we make a new file, `foo.doc`, and `git add` it and `git commit`.  That's what creates snapshot `B`: it has `README.md`—the same *version* of `README.md` as in snapshot `A`—and `Main.java`, again the same as in `A`, plus the new file `foo.doc`.  It also remembers the hash ID of commit `A`.

Then we do something and make `C`, which remembers `B`.  That's what gives us this backwards-looking chain of commits.  All these commits are frozen for all time.  As long as they still exist, the versions of the files that are saved with them, as their snapshots, are also saved for all time.

You have a `Main.java` that's not in this repository at all.  You could just copy it into place, in the work-tree, and `git add` it and make a new commit:

```
A--B--C--D
```

and `D` would have the new version of `Main.java`.  Note that commit `C` is still there, unchanged, frozen for all time.

The only tricky bit here is this: *what exactly is a branch anyway?*  What does it mean for these commits to be "on" some branch(es)?

The answer is: a *branch name*—which is one of the things people sometimes mean when they say "a branch"—holds the hash ID of *one* commit.  We say that the branch name *points to* that commit.  Let's have `master` point to `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

Now let's add another branch name, such as `hello`, but make it point to `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- hello
       \
        D   <-- master
```

Nothing has changed in any of the commits!  (I've drawn `D` on a new row, but that's just to squeeze in my arrows.)  Commits `A` through `D` are now on `master`, and commits `A` through `C` are now on `hello`.

You can create and destroy branch names at any time, pointing to any commit that actually exists, using the `git branch` command.  The easy way to get `hello` to point to `C` is to start with `master` pointing to `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

and use `git branch hello`, which makes the new branch point to the same commit as the current branch / current commit:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, hello
```

We add the special name `HEAD` and attach it to one of these two branch names:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD), hello
```

to show which *branch* we have checked out.  Both branch names identify commit `C`, so that `git checkout master` gets you commit `C`, and `git checkout hello` also gets you commit `C`, but the name `HEAD` remains attached to whichever *name* you used.

*Now* we make our new commit, by copying the file into place in our work-tree, then using `git add`, then `git commit`.  The special trick about making a commit with `git commit` is that, after `git commit` makes the new commit, it *changes the current branch name* so that it points to the new commit:

```
A--B--C   <-- hello
       \
        D   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and we have just want we wanted.

Comment: @isherwood: Git does not store diffs.  (Pack files use delta-compression, but that's below the object storage model.)  In one sense, this doesn't really matter (see the early chapters of [my book](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf)), but Git generally likes to emphasize this aspect of its storage model, if I may anthropomorphize it a bit. (Don't anthropomorphize computers, they hate that!)